# Same DOM element is inserting after the input elements while validating form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am stuck in a problem, I am validating a form, I am inserting the DOM element with the error message using jQuery's `.after()` method after the input field when the input field is focused out. But if the field is empty and the input field is focused and unfocused more than one time the DHTML DOM element is appended more than one time. 
HTML is as:

```
<div class="container">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
        </form>
    </div>
    <style type="text/css">
        .error-form{
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
```

Javascript is as:

```
(function(){
    var form = jQuery('form')[0];
    jQuery.each(form, function(i, v){
        $(v).on('focusout', function(evt){
            var self = $(this);
            if (self.val().length < 1) {
                self.after($('<span />', {
                    text: "This field is required",
                    class: 'error-form'
                }));

            }
        });
    });
})();
```

I tried with the solution like checking if the element is already present than stop appending but wasn't successful. How can I cop with the problem.

***Every suggestion will be appreciated.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are putting the message `after()` the input, before you run validation on that input, check if the `next()` element has the class `error-form`. If so, remove.

```js
(function() {
  var form = jQuery('form')[0];
  jQuery.each(form, function(i, v) {
    $(v).on('focusout', function(evt) {
      if ($(this).next().hasClass('error-form')){
        $(this).next().remove();
      }
      var self = $(this);
      if (self.val().length < 1) {
        self.after($('<span />', {
          text: "This field is required",
          class: 'error-form'
        }));

      }
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
.error-form {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you run validation, you can clear out all the previous messages:

```
$('.error-form').remove();
```

This will remove all of the elements with the `error-form` class, and then your validation will add in any for invalid elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the next element is not allready a `span`.

```
(function(){
    var form = jQuery('form')[0];
    jQuery.each(form, function(i, v){

        $(v).on('focusout', function(evt){
            var self = $(this);
             if (self.val().length < 1 && self.next().is(':not(span)') ) {
                self.after($('<span />', {
                    text: "This field is required",
                    class: 'error-form'
                }));

            }


        });
    });
})();
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/01uc9gec/

Answer (score 0):

If you need more messages like required, email etc for single element, you can add static span without any text after every input and then try changing html only like

```
if($(this).val().length < 1 ) { 

$('span').html('this field is required');

}
```

Finally when all validation are fulfilled hide it

```
$('span').hide();
```

You can also go through library like jQuery validation to look for more customised validations